# Gdata objective-c upload photo error 400 photo data must be set(picasa)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, gdata

Right now I am trying to upload a photo to Picasa using the objective c client like below:

```
GDataServiceGooglePhotos* service =
[self photoService];

// get the URL for the album
NSURL *albumURL = [GDataServiceGooglePhotos
                photoFeedURLForUserID:userEmailAdress albumID:albumName
                   albumName:nil photoID:nil kind:@"album" access:@"all"];

// set a title and description for the new photo
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateFormat  = @"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSSS";
GDataTextConstruct *title, *desc;
title = [GDataTextConstruct textConstructWithString:[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
desc = [GDataTextConstruct textConstructWithString:[descriptionTextfield text]];

GDataEntryPhoto *newPhoto = [GDataEntryPhoto photoEntry];
[newPhoto setTitle:title];
[newPhoto setPhotoDescription:desc];

// attach the photo data
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1.0);
[newPhoto setPhotoData:data];
[newPhoto setPhotoMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
[newPhoto setUploadData:data];
[newPhoto setUploadMIMEType:@"image/jpeg"];
[newPhoto setUploadSlug:title.stringValue];


// now upload it
GDataServiceTicket *ticket;
ticket = [service fetchEntryByInsertingEntry:newPhoto forFeedURL:albumURL delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(addPhotoTicket:finishedWithEntry:error:)];
[service setServiceUploadProgressSelector:nil];
```

And here is my addPhotoTicket:finishedWithEntry:error: method

```
 if (error == nil) {
    NSLog(@"UPLOADED");
} else {
    NSLog(@"THERE WAS AN ERROR");
}
```

I keep getting "There was an error", and failedWithStatus:400 data:Photo data or source id must be included. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: how u did this, can u please brief

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [GooglePhotosSample](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Examples/GooglePhotosSample/GooglePhotosSampleWindowController.m) application, uploading should be done to the URL of an album's `uploadLink`. Don't try to make an album URL manually for uploading. The album ID is not the album's name.

`UIImageJPEGRepresentation` can easily fail; check that it is returning non-nil data.

`setPhotoData:` and `setPhotoMIMEType:` are synonyms for `setUploadData:` and `setUploadMIMEType:`; there is no need to call both.

`setTitle:` and `setPhotoDescription:` have "WithString" versions so there's no need to create a text construct explicitly to set those.

Enable the library's [http logging](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-http-fetcher/wiki/GTMHTTPFetcherIntroduction#HTTP_Logging) to see the actual server requests and responses.

Comment: Can you please post an example of how to get the upload link using an album id? The problem is that I am using a third party service to get the albums, and they only provide me with the album id of the album that I need to upload to.

Comment: can you please tell me how to get the upload link using an album id?